# how to delete an existing jupyter server in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

i'm using remote jupyter server in vscode.i added remote server as the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) says.
But what annoying me now is that i created too many server url but don't know how to delete one.
[image]
Does anyone know how to deal with it? Or i should uninstall and reinstall totally.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command (CMD+SHIFT+P on MAC):

```
>Jupyter: Clear Jupyter server list
```