# How to clear Jupyter Servers in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, jupyterhub

We run our private JupyterHub server and often connect to it from VS Code. Unfortunately, we had a few issues with it when we set up the JupyterHub server. As a consequence, a lot or our users have a long list of previous connections that clutter the list, e.g. like this:

[image]

Is there a way to clear this list of old connections?

If possible, it would be nice to selectively clear the connections one by one, but in the worst case it would be already better to clear the whole list.

I tried `Jupyter: Clear Jupyter server list` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105372/how-to-delete-an-existing-jupyter-server-in-vscode), but it didn't make any difference.